# How to make mouse jump from one screen's border to another screen in a Windows PC with multidisplays?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse, autohotkey

My laptop, running Windows 7 Pro, is connected to a docking station with 3 monitors.

The screens' disposition is something like that :

[image]

- Monitor 1 is 1366x768 (laptop)
- Monitor 2 is 1920x1280
- Monitor 3 is 1080x1920
- Monitor 4 is 1080x1920

The question is

**How can I make my mouse go directly from monitor 1 to monitor 4 or 3, without going through monitor 2 ?**

I have some solutions by using shortcuts or mouse buttons, but I would like a total transparent solution.

Some programs are near to what I am looking for, but doesn't handle this specific configuration :

- http://www.door2windows.com/unlimited-mouse-dont-let-your-screens-border-stop-your-mouse-cursor/ (No multimonitor support)
- Actual Multiple Monitors, multiple monitor supports, ability to go from right side of monitor 3 to left side monitor 4. But stuck in monitor 1.

Maybe an AHK script will help ? Any other hints ?

Thanks !

Regards,

Edit: replace schema with screen capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @joseppinilla and [this script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8400-crazy-scripting-cursor-navigator-105-by-andreone/page-2#entry163556), I wrote this little [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script which resolves my problem :

```
#Persistent
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetTimer, Cursor, 100
Return

Cursor:
  MouseGetPos, XPos, YPos
  If (YPos > 1200) {
        ; From 1 to 4
        If (XPos <= 281)  and (XPos > -1) 
        {
            XPos = -4
        }
        ; From 4 to 1
        If (XPos >= -3) and (XPos < 279)
        {
            XPos = 282
        }
        ; From 3 to 1

        If (XPos <= 1922) and (XPos > 1644)
        {
            XPos = 1641
        }
        ; From 1 to 3
        If (XPos >= 1642)  and (XPos < 1920)
        {
            XPos = 1923
        }


        MouseGetPos, nXPos, nYPos
        ;From 1 to 4
        If (nXpos <= 280) and (nXPos >-1) or
        ; From 4 to 1
        (nXPos >= -2)  and (nXPos < 279) or
        ; From 3 to 1
        (nXPos <= 1921) and (nXPos > 1644) or
        ; From 1 to 3
        (nXPos >= 1643)  and (nXPos < 1920)
        {
            MouseMove, %XPos%, %YPos%, 0  
        }
    }
Return
```

Some details to understand this tiny script :

- 1200 is the Y position of the top of my Monitor 1
- -1 is the X Position of the Right of my Monitor 4
- 279 is the X position of the Left of my monitor 1
- 1644 is the X position of the right of my monitor 1
- 1920 is the X position of the left of my monitor 3

Answer (score 0):

Does your OS or Graphics card driver recognize these three screens natively? because if they do then you should be able to just drag and locate each screen according to your set up in the same tab or window where you choose your main display.

Edit: You should try some Mouse Wrappers. I know these two... but try some others and let us know if you find one that works.

[Mouse Wrapper](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=863837)

[QDWares](http://qdwares-mouse-wrap.software.informer.com/)

Comment: I just replace the schema with a screen capture. As you can see, my OS recongnize all 4 screens and they are positionned accordingly to my physical set-up. However, the screen (1) of my laptop is 1366px large and my main screen (2) is 1920px large. If I put screen (1) near screen (4), I won't be able to resolve my problem when trying to access screen (3) from screen (1).

Comment: Many thanks for you useful answer. By searching for "Mouse Wrapper", I found [this AHK script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8400-crazy-scripting-cursor-navigator-105-by-andreone/page-2#entry163556) which helped me a lot in writing the code below.